# Optimize SQL Query that calculates Subtotal, Discount and Total per Product

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

I have a query that displays the sum of quantity sold, subtotal and total sold per product. The problem is it's taking too long to execute. Am I doing this wrong? I need your help to optimize the query. Also, should I group it by sd.Product_Id or p.Product_Name is fine?

```
SELECT p.Product_Name   `Product Name`,
       SUM(sd.Quantity) `Quantity Sold`,
       SUM(sd.Subtotal) `Subtotal`,
       SUM(sd.Discount_Value) `Total Discount`,
       SUM(sd.Total)    `Total`
FROM Sales_Detail sd
JOIN Product p ON sd.Product_Id = p.Id
WHERE DATE(sd.Purchase_Date) BETWEEN DATE('2017-08-21')
                                 and date('2017-08-25')
GROUP BY p.Product_Name;
```

Comment: If `DATE(sd.Purchase_Date)` is converting a datetime field stop doing that.  specify your between operands to be datetime types also.

Comment: You should have posted it as an answer and not only as a comment. My original query is 200+ seconds. Now down to 3 secs! Thank you!

Comment: But the original rows returned was 1091. The modified query only returns 973. I still need to check what rows got removed

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). In ADDITION, questions about query performance also require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Whether `Purchase_Date` is a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`, the query _as stated_ will check for 5 days.  Removing `DATE()` function call from around a `DATETIME` changes the semantics significantly -- it looses all matches _except_ midnight of the 25th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an index on the `Sales_Detail.Purchase_Date` column, and then rewrite your query to remove the function surrounding that column so it can take advantage of the index:

```
SELECT p.Product_Name `Product Name`, 
  SUM(sd.Quantity) `Quantity Sold`, 
  SUM(sd.Subtotal) `Subtotal`, 
  SUM(sd.Discount_Value) `Total Discount`, 
  SUM(sd.Total) `Total`
FROM Sales_Detail sd
JOIN Product p ON sd.Product_Id = p.Id
WHERE sd.Purchase_Date >= '2017-08-21' 
  AND sd.Purchase_Date < '2017-08-26'
GROUP BY p.Product_Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a noob question, should I be worried by the date not having the 00:00:00 in the where statement?

Comment: If `Purchase_Date` is a `DATE`, you have excluded the entire first day.

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter - a datetime literal can have or omit 00:00:00 -- it makes no difference.  Even when compared to either a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @Ike Walker
May I know what happens if the Sales_Detail.Purchase_Date is not indexed? And also why >= AND < instead of using BETWEEN?

Comment: If the column is not indexed then MySQL will do a table scan, which is slow. I'm assuming the `Purchase_Date` is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, so I want to include values between `2017-08-21 00:00:00` and `2017-08-25 23:59:59`, and I personally find it simpler and more readable to write it as I did.

Answer (score 0):

`sd` needs `INDEX(Purchase_Date)` *and* rewrite:

```
WHERE sd.Purchase_Date >= '2017-08-21'
      sd.Purchase_Date  < '2017-08-26'  -- next day
```

This works for any flavor of date/datetime/etc.

This may be even better, since it avoids calculating leapyears, etc:

```
WHERE sd.Purchase_Date >= '2017-08-21'
      sd.Purchase_Date  < '2017-08-21' + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Also, consider changing the `GROUP BY` to

```
GROUP BY sd.Product_Id
```

since it *should* be identical.  And, then, have

```
INDEX(Purchase_Date, Product_Id)
```

This would be "covering" and will probably be more optimal by handling the `GROUP BY` with the index (instead of a subsequent 'filesort').